# How to change the properties of the state object while maintaining the previous values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, onchange, setstate

Essence: There are 4 fields where values are entered, it is necessary to write down these values.

Problem: Each time the event handler is called, the entire object is overwritten with a change in the value of one property, the remaining property values are 0, the values entered in other fields are not saved.

```
class BlockInput extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: {
            width: 0,
            length: 0,
            thickness: 0,
            height: 0
        }
    }
    this.clickChange = this.clickChange.bind(this);
    }

    clickChange(event){
         if (this.state.data.hasOwnProperty(event.target.name)) {
            const upd = {};
            upd[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
            this.setState({data: { ...this.state.data, ...upd}})
        }
         console.log(this.state.data)
    }
    render(){
        const {name, id, className} = this.props;
        return (
            <Input type="text" onChange={this.clickChange} name={id} autocomplete="off" placeholder="0 см" ></Input>
        )
    }
}
```

I enter width into the input - the console answers: width: '2', length: 0, thickness: 0, height: 0

After I enter length into input - the console answers: width: 0, length: '2', thickness: 0, height: 0

Comment: Hi! Where are the rest of your inputs? Do you call this BlockInput component 4 times? Because if that is the case, they each have their own separate state, so that might be causing the issue

Comment: Why do not you simply do: `this.setState({data: { ...this.state.data, [event.target.name]: event.target.data}})`?

Comment: Yes, that is most likely the reason. I wanted to get the status of other components in one component.... thank